# How to search for word in a string and print differently based on the case of the match?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a program to test if a word appears in a string and to print a different message depending on the number of upper case letters in the match.

For instance, searching for `robot` in a string such as `I saw a robot in the street...` would print `There is a small robot.`, in `I saw a rOBOt in the alleyway!` it would print `There is a medium size robot.`, and if the string contains `ROBOT` it would print `There is a big robot.`.

This is what I have tried:

```py
a = input("Line: ")
b = a.split()
if "robot" in b:
   c = list("robot")
   if c[0].isupper() or c[1].isupper() or c[2].isupper() or c[3].isupper() or c[4].isupper():
     print("Small robot...")
   else:
     print("No robots here.")
```

I know it's kind of lengthy but it's how much I can do right now. How can I get it to find the word `robot` in the string, regardless of position and to print the correct output?

Comment: To get you started, you are defining `c` as a list of all lower case characters, so your if-statement is never going to evaluate to `True`. You need to compare against the actual input you received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd take a simple approach. First check if the lowercased keyword exists in the sentence. If not: check if the uppercased keyword exists. If not: check if the lowercased keyword exists in the lowercased words.

```
keyword = 'robot'
sentence = input("Line: ")
words = sentence.split()
if keyword.lower() in words:
    print("There is a small robot.")
elif keyword.upper() in words:
    print('There is a big robot.')
elif keyword.lower() in (word.lower() for word in words):
    print('There is a medium size robot.')
else:
    print('There is no robot.')
```

With minor modifications you could even check for different cases (e.g. "There is a robot and a second rOboT").

```
keyword = 'robot'
sentence = input("Line: ")
words = sentence.split()
keyword_found = False
if keyword.lower() in words:
    keyword_found = True
    print("There is a small robot.")
if keyword.upper() in words:
    keyword_found = True
    print('There is a big robot.')
if keyword.lower() in (word.lower() for word in words if word not in (keyword.lower(), keyword.upper())):
    keyword_found = True
    print('There is a medium size robot.')
if not keyword_found:
    print('There is no robot.')
```

An explanation for the following line:

```
if keyword.lower() in (word.lower() for word in words if word not in (keyword.lower(), keyword.upper())):
```

In the condition we have to throw out an existing all lowercase or all uppercase keyword. That was not needed in the simple version of the code because that part would never have been reached due to the `elif`.

Comment: Thank you, this is actually what I am looking for :)

Answer (score 3):

You can check if a character is upper case via `isupper()`:

```
s = "rOBOt"
percent_upper = sum(char.isupper() for char in s) / len(s)
print(percent_upper) # 0.6
```

Then just use that percent value in your if statements:

```
if percent_upper == 0:
    print("small")
elif percent_upper == 1.0:
    print("large")
else:
    print("medium")
```

-- edit --

Here is a more complete solution that finds robot in the sentence:

```
import re

def get_robot_size(s):
    percent_upper = sum(char.isupper() for char in s) / len(s)
    return percent_upper

s = "I saw a ROBOt in the street"
robot_search = re.search(r'\brobot\b', s, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
if not robot_search: # no robot found
    print("No robot found")
else:
    robot_str = robot_search.group()
    robot_size = get_robot_size(robot_str) # Get the percentage of capital letters
    if robot_size == 0:
        print("small")
    elif robot_size == 1.0:
        print("large")
    else:
        print("medium")
```

Comment: Interesting approach. Can be simplified to `sum(char.isupper() for char in s) / len(s)` or even to `sum(map(str.isupper, s)) / len(s)`

Comment: Missed that. Thank you.

Comment: What happens if I wanted to make it so that if there is no word "robot" in the line then print ```No robots here!```? And also, I am looking for how to check only for the word robot, is it possible to do?

Comment: I see some stuff missing. One sec.

Comment: @Error - Syntactical Remorse And, one last thing, what if I wanted - for example, if s was ```I went to robotfest and it was fun!```, can it print ```No robots here.```?

Comment: See the update. A little more complicated because you need to use regex.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html) to first find if the word is present in a case insensitive way, and then count how many letters are upper case.

For instance:

```
import re

sentence = "I can see a mixed-case rObOT here"

# Search for the word 'robot' anywhere and regardless of case
matches = re.match(r"(?i).*\b(robot)\b.*", sentence)

if matches:
    matching_word = matches.group(1)

    # Iterate each letter in the match to count upper case ones
    uppercase_count = 0
    for l in matching_word:
        if l.isupper():
            uppercase_count += 1

    # Print something different based on the number of upper case letters found
    if uppercase_count < 2:
        print("small robot")
    elif uppercase_count < 4:
        print("medium robot")
    else:
        print("big robot")
else:
    print("no robot")
```

This is very specific to your example but can easily be generalised to any word.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
import re
a = input("Line: ")
b = a.split()
c = False
for i in range(len(b)):
    if 'robot' == b[i]:
        print('Small Robot')
        c = True
        break
    elif 'ROBOT' == b[i]:
        print('Big Robot')
        c = True
        break
    elif 'robot' == b[i].lower():
        if re.search('[a-z]', b[i]) and re.search('[A-Z]', b[i]):
            print('Medium Robot')
            c = True
            break
if not c:
    print('No Robot')
```